# NGINX to redirect non http (raw socket) and http(web browser) traffic

Tags: nginx

Title: NGINX to redirect non http (raw socket) and http(web browser) traffic

The server has both non http request from raw socket and http request from web browser via port 443. The idea is to check the request, and pass the non http request to port 8086 and the http request to port 81.
This is my idea of implementing:

```
http {
  ...
  server {
    listen       80;
    # ... Redirect to port 443
  }

  # HTTPS server
  server {
      listen       443 ssl;
      server_name  cims2.crysberg.com;

      ssl_certificate      cert_chain.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key  private.key;

      ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
      ssl_session_timeout  5m;

      ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

      # The raw socket doesn't have user agent
      if( $http_user_agent = "") {
        ####################################
        ###   redirect location to /rawSocket
        ####################################
      }

      location / {
        #pass the request to apache server
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:81;            
      }

      location /rawSocket {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8068;
      }
  }
}
```

My questions are :

1. Do I need to listen to raw socket communication using stream {}
   block?
2. And if the answer to question 1 is yes, can I both have
   stream{} block listens to raw socket on 443 and server block listen
   to http request on 443?
3. Is my idea of implement correct ? How can I
   redirect raw socket request location to /rawSocket? I have tried
   “rewrite ^(.*) $1/rawSocket; ” and test it using “openssl s_client
   -connect xxx.com:443”. But it doesn't work because the raw Socket doesn't have the location/header.

Comment: need a single `server` for tcp/udp proxy http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#example

Comment: @Deadooshka could you be a bit more verbose please?  Not sure how your link answers Thai's question.  In a nutshell he needs to watch port 443 and redirect standard http/https requests on to an Aoache web-server, and non-header raw socket data to another app listening on an internal port (in this case 8068).

Comment: `proxy_pass` inside a `location` is related to the http_proxy_module. I tested config with stream{}/http{} on 443, and nginx always handle first listed block in config. It seems nginx can't make a logical choice between modules on the same port. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Interesting.  Will have to test that more in-depth.  Thanks for your response!